# When creating Bitmap in ImageView when is the time to use the Thread?

Tags: android, bitmap

during

```
Bitmap b1 = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(pathName1,
                    MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
```

and `Bitmap bmp1 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b1, nWidth, nHeight, true);` and `imageView1.setImageBitmap(bmp1);`

When is the right time to use Thread in creating Bitmap? And when to used the `View.post`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use next methods in thread.

```
Bitmap b1 = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(pathName1,
                    MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
Bitmap bmp1 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b1, nWidth, nHeight, true);
```

And set image in main thread

```
imageView1.setImageBitmap(bmp1);
```

Comment: what do u mean? Bitmap b1 = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(pathName1,
                    MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
Bitmap bmp1 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b1, nWidth, nHeight, true); in other thread and imageView1.setImageBitmap(bmp1); in main thread?

Comment: You can't change ui interface in not UI thread. Use runOnUiThread() 
function for that.

Comment: what is the difference in runOnUiThread() vs View.post? runOnUiThread() can accept many ui changes and view.post for single view changes?

Comment: I think you can do a lot changes in View.post because runnable you put it that method will executed in UI thread. But I think that more logical use that to change that specific View. In your case I don't see difference between that ways. Also If you will use AssyncTask for create bitmap you don't use View post or runOnUiThreat you can just do imageView1.setImageBitmap(bmp1) in postExecute method. Maybe  you know that)

Comment: yup but im planing to use more on java side and i want know more about java way because they say java classes can implements all what android offer, but i like also the asynctask make my coding more easy.

Comment: follow up question how about decode the bitmap and bitmapfactory.options.insamplesize? does this two also need to be run in a thread?